# Rank an array of tuples

Tags: python, ranking

I have an array

```
array = [('item1',90),('item2',76),('item3',83),('item4',90)]
```

and I'd like to rank it like

```
ranking = [(0,'item1'),(0,'item4'),(2,'item3'),(3,'item2')] // (1)
```

This is what I've done it so far, using [ranking](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ranking):

```
from ranking import *

>>> array.sort(key=lambda x: x[1],reverse = True)
>>> print [i for i in list(Ranking([i[1] for i in array]))]
```

This is what I get:

```
[(0, 90), (0, 90), (2, 83), (3, 76)] // (2)
```

Can anyone help me to get from (2) to (1)? I don't really need to use `ranking`. I accept any other solution.

Comment: `sorted(array, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))`

Comment: Would you review my answer below, I think it's a very good one. :)

Comment: Do you have any feedback for my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = [('item1',90),('item2',76),('item3',83),('item4',90)]
srt = sorted(array,key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
rankings = []
rank = 0
from itertools import groupby
for k,v in groupby(srt,lambda x: x[1]): # group by score
    grp = [(rank,tup[0]) for tup in v] # get item tup[0] and put it in a tuple with the rank
    rankings += grp
    rank += len(grp) # increase rank for next grouping
print(rankings)
[(0, 'item1'), (0, 'item4'), (2, 'item3'), (3, 'item2')]
```

Comment: very nice. but this is a dense rank. i'm looking for a ranking like [0,0,2,3]

Comment: @BrunoCalza, actually doesn't,  order is not maintained, will have a look and see if I can fix it

Comment: yep. it's perfect. i chose another solution though. it fits me better. thank you very much anyway

Comment: no worries, a word of warning your selected answer will fail with `array = [('item1',90),('item1',90),('item2',76),('item3',83),('item4',90)]` I used enumerate originally but it only works when items are repeated 2 or less times

Comment: this is bad. I'll do some tests later to check this out.

Comment: you're right. did some tests. your answer is more complete. marked it as accepted. thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Pandas DataFrame to do this. I'd recommend this solution as it's very semantically designed for the purpose for which you wish to put it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([('item1',90),('item2',76),
                                ('item3',83),('item4',90)])
```

Here's the raw dataframe, before we manipulate it:

```
>>> df
       0   1
0  item1  90
1  item2  76
2  item3  83
3  item4  90
```

Now we'll select column 1 and rank it descending, and add the rank back into the dataframe (using the min method):

```
>>> df['rank'] = df[1].rank(method='min', ascending=False)
>>> df
       0   1  rank
0  item1  90     1
1  item2  76     4
2  item3  83     3
3  item4  90     1
```

Now we'll convert our desired columns back into a list of tuples, excluding the index:

```
>>> l = list(df[[0, 'rank']].to_records(index=False))
>>> l
[('item1', 1.0), ('item2', 4.0), ('item3', 3.0), ('item4', 1.0)]
```

We can get it into the desired state with a list comprehension:

```
>>> l2 = [(i, int(j-1)) for i, j in l]
>>> l2
[('item1', 0), ('item2', 3), ('item3', 2), ('item4', 0)]
```

Comment: very nice man. i have not thought of using pandas. i am going to stick with a solution that does not use it though. thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [('item1',90),('item2',76),('item3',83),('item4',90)]

def s(t):
    return t[1]

array.sort(reverse = True, key = s)

def rank(array):
    res = []
    for index, tup in enumerate(array):
        if index == 0:
            res.append(tuple([ index, tup[0]]))
        elif tup[1] == array[index -1][1]:
            res.append(tuple([index -1, tup[0]]))
        else:
            res.append(tuple([index , tup[0]]))
    return res
r = rank(array)
print r
```

Output - **[(0, 'item1'), (0, 'item4'), (2, 'item3'), (3, 'item2')]**

This might be very lenghty solution but i hope this would work fine

Comment: indeed this does not work for items repeated more than 2 times

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ranking installed, so can't test it but the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org//ranking/) says Ranking() supports passing a key function, to select values from the list.

I would suggest trying something like this:

```
print Ranking(array, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [('item1',90),('item2',76),('item3',83),('item4',90)]
values = sorted(v for k, v in array)
d = dict(zip(values, range(len(values)-1, -1, -1)))
print sorted(( (d[i],item) for (item, i) in array ))
```

This produces the output:

```
[(0, 'item1'), (0, 'item4'), (2, 'item3'), (3, 'item2')]
```

#### How it works

`values` contains a sorted list of the values:

```
[76, 83, 90, 90]
```

We then create a dictionary `d` to rank order them.  `d` is:

```
{76: 3, 83: 2, 90: 0}
```

Comment: this is not really what i need. thks!